# STM32:-Why is it required to make pins AF(Alternate function)

Tags: stm32

I want to configure SPI1 in stm32f103. Why is it required to make pins AF(Alternate function)? Cant it just be input or output? What is actually happening when the pins are AF?

Answer (score 4):

Those pins can be connected to several different peripheral blocks, by setting the alternate function, you're configuring a multiplexer within the IC to connect the pin to the correct peripheral block for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Output pins can be controlled either by the GPIO `ODR` registe, or a peripheral. There must be a way to say which one has the control. If you don't need all output signals of a peripheral, you can leave the corresponding pin as GPIO, and use the pin for something else.

- If the pin is set as General Purpose Output, then the output voltage level is determined by the `ODR` register. The peripheral controller has no effect on the output.
- If the pin is set as Alternate Function Output, then the peripheral determines the pin output, and the corresponding `ODR` register is disconnected from the pin.
- If the pin is set as input, then there is no difference. The pin state is available both in the `IDR` register and to the peripheral controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your [STM32F103](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/0d/93/e0/d7/77/bf/4c/54/CD00210843.pdf/files/CD00210843.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00210843.pdf), Page 26 describes what would be the value of each pin after reset. Making it AF (alternate Function) tells the processor to make this pin as your desired functionality, SPI1 in your case. If you dont do it then your Pin will always behave as default Pin.